# adding Date and Time in javascript to get in ISOFormat

Tags: javascript, reactjs, datetime, ecmascript-6

I got the date in ISOFormats and time in 12hrs format. i need to combine togeather and get the output in ISOFormat using javascript. Im doing this in reactJs so using external libraries is fine

```
date = "2019-02-19T00:00:00.000Z"
startTime = "04.42PM"

outputDateTime = "2019-02-19T11:12:37.680Z"
```

Comment: Can you give a sample input and output?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [momentjs `parse` function](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/).

Use it to convert the dates to `moment` objects and directly add them using the `add` function.

[Example here](http://jsfiddle.net/jyc7Lqs1/)

Answer (score 0):

If you go pure vanilla I think this is fairly simple (AFAIK you only need hours and minutes and the zone is always fixed, if not, upgrade).

```
var yourDate = "2019-02-19T00:00:00.000Z";
var yourTime = "04.42PM"
var dat = yourDate.split("T")[0];
var minutes = yourTime.split(".")[1].slice(0,2);
var isPm = yourTime.split(".")[1].slice(2) === "PM";
var hours = isPm ? parseInt(yourTime.split(".")[0]) + 12 : yourTime.split(".")[0];

var date = new Date(dat+ "T" +hours+":"+minutes+":00Z");
```

Basically, I decomposed the input strings into interesting parts, compensated for PM if needed and put them back together :)